# jQuery delegate each function

Tags: jquery, datatables, each

I am using [jQuery DataTable](https://datatables.net/) to display a list of options. Now this table consists of multiple pages and users have an option to de-select/select options from DataTable entries using a checkbox. I am successfully able to initiate a delegate event on all the checkboxes, however, the problem is when I have an option to de-select/select all the checkboxes, it just works for the first page. The other checkboxes still remain selected. I am not sure, how to delegate it for all pages. Can anyone please throw some light here. Here is my code:

```
$('body').delegate('[name="selectAll"]', 'change', function () {
if($(this).is(':checked')){
$('[name="all_barcodes[]"]').each(function(){
        this.checked = true;
    }); 
}else{
$('[name="all_barcodes[]"]').each(function(){
        this.checked = false;
    }); 
}

});
```

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot select / de-select hidden rows in datatable because datatable keep only those tr  which are visible and removes rest, which means you will not have dom elements for hidden rows and hence cannot do jquery on it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with delegation, which is about binding event handlers for elements that are added dynamically. Your question is about setting the state of DOM elements (or in this case, the state of DOM elements that will be added sometime in the future).

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar: So, what solution do you suggest?

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, you are right, any idea to get it working?

Comment: @ChintanParekh, when you load hidden rows using pagination, filter etc, then check state of select all checkbox and select / deselect visible checkboxes. it is workaround.

Comment: That's a good idea man..thanks a lot..! In the mean time if you could post a working code (only if not a trouble), would be great. Thanks a lot still, this gets me working :)